# Yii remove index.php from url on NGINX

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, yii, url-routing

I've moved Yii 1 website to a new Ubuntu server with NGINX and all works fine except cleaned URLs without index.php part. For example page http://****/site/about redirects to homepage but http://****/index.php/site/about shows correct page. My current server block configuration file contains this location rules:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

I've also tried using

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
```

but it end up with redirect loop.

Seems like rewrite /index.php$uri?$args never validates against $uri check.

In Yii config I have

```
'urlManager' => array (
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'caseSensitive' => false,
            'rules' => array (
                '<public_url:about>'=>'site/about',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                ....
```

So the question is how to make http://****/site/about show same page as http://****/index.php/site/about request?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like rewrite /index.php$uri?$args never validates against $uri
>   check.

No. The `location \.php$` only matches URIs which end with `.php`. After you append path info, it no longer matches.

The correct way to process php scripts with path info, is to replace the terminating `$` with `(/|$)` and use the `fastcgi_split_path_info` directive to separate the path info from the script path name. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for details.

Comment: Why then direct request http://****/index.php/site/about is processed correctly?
Changing location to  \.php(/|$)  didn't change anything in my case.
`location ~* \.php(/|$) {
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
               include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       }`

Comment: That works because it is rewritten to `/index.php` by the `location /` block.

Comment: Why do you set PATH_INFO to script name? You should be using `$fastcgi_path_info` now anyway.

Comment: i've removed $fatscgi_path_info as it doesn't change anything. So my php location looks now like this: `location ~* \.php(/|$) {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}`

Comment: I don't understand then why `http://****/index.php/site/about` is rewritten to `/index.php` and `http://****/site/about` is not. Shouldn't it be vice versa? part without index.php should be rewritten with index.php and than it will fall to  location ~* \.php(/|$) ?  What happens now is that all request without index.php are fallback to site frontpage http://****/index.php

Comment: You originally had PATH_INFO set to a bogus value. Perhaps you should remove PATH_INFO and see if that fixes your original problem and do not try to rewrite to `/index.php$uri` as it is a level of complexity that you probably do not need.

Comment: @RicharsSmith : removing PATH_INFO from original config didn't have any affect.